# OS X upgrade 10.13.2 (17C88) crashed GAE PHP - How to fix?

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, macos-high-sierra

Launching an app show this:

```
bad runtime process port ['']

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/_php_runtime.py", line 103, in <module>
_run_file(__file__, globals())
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/_php_runtime.py", line 97, in _run_file
execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/php/runtime/runtime.py", line 39, in <module>
from google.appengine.tools.devappserver2 import wsgi_server
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/wsgi_server.py", line 34, in <module>
import ipaddr
ImportError: No module named ipaddr
```

Have tried reinstall, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by commenting out the line `load ipaddr` in `wsgi_server.py`. Working OK so far.